# Why did my DocumentRoot change?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, documentroot

My document root (suddenly and unexpectedly) changed to `/htdocs` from `/var/www`. This happened after I restarted apache2.

The only thing I changed was the `httpd.conf` file which now reads as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName hostname
    UseCanonicalName ON
</VirtualHost>
```

I've greped through the entire `/etc` directory looking for `DocumentRoot` and they all say `/var/www`.

I removed the `000-default` from `sites-enabled` and replaced it with one that is named `default`. Changing this back doesn't appear to have an effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that by adding a `<VirtualHost>` without a `DocumentRoot` it will default to the basic Apache2 `DocumentRoot`. Contrary to what the package (and everything else says), the source gives the `DocumentRoot` as `/htdocs`.

The solution is to add `DocumentRoot: /var/www` to the `httpd.conf` file.

Source: [wiki.apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DistrosDefaultLayout#Apache_2.2_default_layout_.28apache.org_source_package.29:)